# How to find out whether a jQuery function is synchronous or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have one jQuery function in my code for which I think it might be asynchronous but I couldn't find out if that's true. I have a guess that, if a function has a callback then it is asynchronous ; otherwise it is synchronous.

In my case it is the function [.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/). Using the logic from above I guess it is synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can try to do this:

- Look at the API documentation
- Look at the return type (if it returns a `Promise` it's asynchronous)
- Look at the Source code

The particular function you're looking at, there's nothing to indicate that it's asynchronous in the docs/return type. It's just making a DOM manipulation I believe which has to be done on the main thread anyway, there's no slow code in there that could be done async.

The function itself I believe is [unwrap](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a684e6ba836f7c553968d7d026ed7941e1a612d8/src/wrap.js#L65) (maybe not the exact version) but you can see there's nothing in there that looks async.